# All routes giving 404 in flask despite the routes.py being successfully imported

Tags: flask, routes

I currently working on a flask backend but have hit an issue where all routes return a 404 despite the routes.py apparently running.

routes.py:

```
import sys, os, json
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
CORS(app)


@app.route('/', endpoint='index')
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET'], endpoint='index')
@cross_origin()
def index():
    print('Hello world!', file=sys.stderr)

    return render_template('index.html', title='home')


@app.route('/projects', endpoint='projects')  # route for projects showcase including json project data loading
@cross_origin()
def projects():
    projects = os.path.join(app.static_folder, 'data', 'projects.json')

    with open(projects) as pData:
        data = json.load(pData)

    return render_template('projects.html', title='showcase', data=data)


@app.route('/contact', endpoint='contact')
def contact():
    return render_template('contact.html', title='contact')


print('Hello routes!', file=sys.stderr) #testing line
```

When I launch it the output is this:

```
 * Serving Flask app 'ClayG' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
Hello routes!
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
Hello routes!
 * Debugger PIN: 274-753-929
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

the print function at the end of routes.py runs so my app is making it through, but when i visit localhost:5000 I get a 404 with only this in the terminal output

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Feb/2022 17:20:29] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

The other files and file structure

```
.
├── ClayG.py
├── .flaskenv
├── app
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── routes.py
│   └── __init__.py
```

ClayG.py

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))
from app import app
```

.flaskenv

```
FLASK_APP=ClayGale
FLASK_ENV=development
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask

from . import routes

app = Flask(__name__)
```

config.py

```
class Config:
    STATIC_FOLDER = 'static'
    TEMPLATES_FOLDER = 'templates'
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = True
```

One thing i've noticed is that adding FLASK_ENV = 'development' to the config class is that it still launches as production and I can only get it to launch in development with the .flaskenv file. I'm unfortunately just stumped as for what to do from here so any wisdom on what to try would be helpful.

Comment: You don't have to specify the endpoint in the route decorator. The upcoming function will always be the endpoint, due to the decorator wrapping around the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created two Flask apps. One in `routes.py` with the endpoints, and a new one in `__init__.py` which is completely empty. You should use the previously created app in the `__init__.py` file:

```
from . import routes

app = routes.app
```

Comment: That did the trick! Now I feel pretty silly